# Swift open local HTML file with parameters

Tags: html, swift, uiwebview

I have a local **HTML** file that I would like to load in a `UIWebView`, but would also like to pass a parameter inside. I can load the HTML file

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("apprules", withExtension: "html")!))
```

I would like to pass the local to the **HTML** like `apprules.html?lang=ja`. Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Swift 3 and up:

```
let url1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apprules", withExtension: "html")!
let url2 = URL(string: "?lang=ja", relativeTo: url1)!
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: url2))
```

### Swift 2 and below:

```
let url1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("apprules", withExtension: "html")!
let url2 = NSURL(string: "?lang=ja", relativeToURL: url1)!
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url2))
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to correct `let url2 = NSURL(string: "?lang=ja", relativeToURL: url1)!`

Comment: Fatty fingers... sorry

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3, I revised codes. Thanks guys. This post helps me a lot.

```
    let url1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apprules", withExtension: "html")!
    let url2 = NSURL(string: "?lang=ja", relativeTo: url1)!
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: url2 as URL) as URLRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Swift 5:**

```swift
let url1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apprules", withExtension: "html")!
let url2 = URL(string: "?lang=ja", relativeTo: url1)!
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url2) 
WKWebView.load(myRequest)
```